# Descrição da notificação da medalha "Aniversariante"

Tags: debate, medalhas

Então, hoje para meu espanto recebi a medalha de aniversariante

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na notificação da mesma diz, entre outras coisas,

> Membro ativo por um ano, obtendo **pelo menos** uma reputação de 200

Acontece que eu tenho reputação de 200 há pouco tempo (menos de 1 ano) e hoje quando a reputação chegou aos 210 é que ganhei essa medalha. A meu ver e pela descrição, dado que sou um utilizador ativo faz mais de 2 anos, essa medalha devia ter sido ganha quando atingi os 200 e não apenas quando passei dos 200.

Será que na descrição o **pelo menos** está realmente correto?

Comment: Parece que ele poderia ser melhorada, mas também não faz muita diferença, tem casos bem piores.

Comment: Talvez seja até o caso de consultarmos o Staff da rede, moderador não tem acesso direto à implementação.

Comment: Você obteu a reputação dentro do ano, não acho que precisava ser distribuído, sua conta tem 2 anos e no segundo ano, mesmo que no "final" você levantou os 200 pontos necessário (100 provavelmente por associação). Seria isso?

Comment: @Bacco pois porque pode ser um problema geral dado que no inglês tem «earning *at least* 200 reputation.».

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não sei se compreendi o que dizes. Se o que procuras saber é se eu ganhei 100 de reputação derivado de reputação noutras redes, então sim.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 o 100 só foi parte da "soma", para supor o total de score em um ano, o que importa (e se entendi a medalha) é que você poderia ter ficado ativo 2019/Março/25 até 2020/Fevereiro/29 com uma média de 100 pontos, e antes de 2020/Março/25 você poderia conseguir mais 100 pontos que isso contaria para sua "atividade de um ano" + "200 pontos", então me parece certo o que é dito na medalha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi a visão. De acordo com essa visão o *pelo menos* 200 está correto se considerarmos que estamos a falar que esses 200 forem obtidos no mesmo ano E se o caso não for esse implica que a reputação total seja maior do que os 200. Eu diria que mesmo nesse caso (que n sei bem se é mesmo assim) a descrição continua sem estar totalmente correta pois está ligada a uma outra condição

Comment: Acho que a questão aí é o "obtendo". Considerando que todos começam com 1 ponto, se sua pontuação era 200, então você só tinha obtido 199

Comment: @hkotsubo pois tbm é uma visão possível

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, estamos discutindo se é `>= 200` ou `> 200`, sabendo da implementação acertar a grafia é fácil. Pode tambem ser o caso do `obtendo` vs `tendo`, mas acho que a implementação seria mais complexa.

Comment: No [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/401803) tem uma fórmula: "*Have a reputation of at least (number of years since registration) × 200 + 1 (starting reputation)*" - então me parece que é `> 200`

Comment: @hkotsubo faz todo sentido, já que todos começamos com 1, logo é 200 "fechado" que você ganha/obtem em atividades no site, e o 1 é de graça. Só faltou dizer na medalha que o 1 é free :), então ao meu ver a descrição esta aceitável, no máximo colocar uma explicação sobre esse ponto inicial (o que talvez seja exagero).